# Am receiving what I think is a syntax error for an array, do not know what it wants be to fix

Tags: java

Have to create a program that uses a SuperHero class, which uses a Name Class and Date class. In the main code, am receiving an error when assign attributes to the hero object.

```
public class JavaProgram{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Date [] birthDay = new Date [3];
        Name [] name = new Name [3];
        SuperHero [] hero = new SuperHero [3];

        for (int i = 0; i < hero.length; i++){
            birthDay[i] = new Date();
            name[i] = new Name();
            hero[i] = new SuperHero();
        }
        birthDay[1].setDate(10,10,87);
        birthDay[2].setDate(5,10,99);
        birthDay[3].setDate(3,12,79);
        name[1].setName("Michael");
        name[2].setName("Scott");
        name[3].setName("Jim");


        SuperHero hero [1] = new SuperHero(name[1], "Suit", "Cape", "Flying", birthDay[1] );
        SuperHero hero [2] = new SuperHero(name[2], "Suit", "No Cape", "Flying", birthDay[2] );
        SuperHero hero [3] = new SuperHero(name[3], "Suit", "Cape", "Flying", birthDay[3] );
    }
}
```

```
    private Name name;
    private String suit;
    private String cape;
    private Date birthDay;
    private String power;

    public SuperHero(Name name, String suit, String cape, String Power,Date birthDay){
        this.name = name;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.cape = cape;
        this.power = power;
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }


    public Date getBirthDay(){
        return this.birthDay;
    }

    public Name getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setSuit (String b){
        suit = b;
    }

    public String getSuit(){
        return suit;
    }

    public void setCape (String t){
        cape = t;
    }

    public String getCape(){
        return cape;
    }

    public void setPower(String v){
        power = v;
    }

    public String getPower(){
        return power;
    }
}
```

```
public class Date
{
  private int month;
  private int day;
  private int year;

  public Date() { month = 0; day = 0; year = 0; }

  public void setDate( int m, int d, int y )
  {
    month = m; day = d; year = y;
  }

  public String getDateString()
  {
    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
  }
}
```

```
public class Name{
    private String name;

    public void setName (String n){
        name = n;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

This error occurs when I try to compile the main code:

```
JavaProgram.java:20: error: ']' expected
        SuperHero hero [1] = new SuperHero(name[1], "Suit", "Cape", "Flying", birthDay[1] );
                        ^
JavaProgram.java:21: error: ']' expected
        SuperHero hero [2] = new SuperHero(name[2], "Suit", "No Cape", "Flying", birthDay[2] );
                        ^
JavaProgram.java:22: error: ']' expected
        SuperHero hero [3] = new SuperHero(name[3], "Suit", "Cape", "Flying", birthDay[3] );
                        ^
3 errors
```

Comment: You don't need `SuperHero` before `hero`. Also, array indices start at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are wrong / problematic here:

1: You're not accessing the hero array properly. Accesing the n-th element of the hero array is done like:

```
hero[n]
```

To assign a value to the n-th position in the hero Array you need

```
hero[n] = new SuperHero( ... )
```

2: In Java arrays are 0-indexed. Which means an array of size 3 has the indexes 0, 1 and 2 `hero[3]` and `name[3]` will both result in an IndexOutOfBoundsException.